# Data from useState not rendering

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to set the value of useState to an array of data fetched from google firestore. The function doing this is triggered in a useEffect hook. The useState hook seems to be working, as the state is as expected when i log it to the console, but when i try to render components by maping over the array, the screen remains blank. I have also tried using a FlatList but the same error persists

```
export default function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  //define use stares
    const [allListings,setListings] = useState(null);
    const [listingsLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    //get posts
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      //init firebase if not already init-ed
      let app;
      if (getApps().length ===0 ){ 
        app = initializeApp(config);}
      else{ app = getApps().app;}

      let listings = [];

      //get firestore
      const db = getFirestore();
      const q = query(collection(db, "Listings"));
      
      //get all docs from collection
      onSnapshot(q,(querySnapshot)=>{
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
          //get image url 
            let imgSrc;
            getImage(doc).then(value =>{
              //add docment data to listings list
                imgSrc = value;
                listings.push({ id: doc.id,imgUrl:imgSrc, ...doc.data() });
            })
        })
    })

    //set listings state
    setListings(listings);

    //change loaded state
    if (!listingsLoaded) {
      setLoaded(true);
    }

    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetchPosts();
    },[])


    //display listings if loaded
    if(listingsLoaded)
    {
      console.log(allListings);
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         
      <View>
      <Header navigation={navigation}></Header>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>{allListings.size}</Text>
      {allListings.map((item) => (
        <Listing listingName={item.listingName}></Listing>
      ))}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.nav}>
        <BottomNav navigation={navigation}></BottomNav>
      </View>
  
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
    );}

    //else show blank homescreen
    else{
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
      <Header navigation={navigation}></Header>
      </View>
      <View>
      <Text>Im going to screem</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.nav}>
        <BottomNav navigation={navigation}></BottomNav>
      </View>
  
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
    );
      }
}
```